# What is the difference between an encryption protocol and an encryption standard?

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between an encryption protocol and an encryption standard?

Am I missing something here? Or are they in fact two different concepts altogether?

Comment: What do you know already there? `A standard is a technical document designed to be used as a rule, guideline or definition` that can include  protocols.

Answer (score 2):

A protocol is a standard, in the sense that multiple parties agree to use it (as is required for a communication protocol). However a standard-standard is very widely used and has some kind of official backing. Examples of standard-standards would be Data Encryption Standard, Advanced Encryption Standard, and Internet Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The "OpenPGP Standard" (standard), versus "GPG" (implementation of the standard), versus "an RSA based hybdrid cryptosystem using AES for the symmetric encryption" (a protocol defined by the standard and implemented by an implementation of it).